# Doctrine - entities not being fetched

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have some entities with a one-to-many / many-to-one relationship -

Production class -

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductionsKeywords", mappedBy="production")
 */
protected $productionKeywords;
```

ProductionsKeywords class -

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Production", inversedBy="productionKeywords")
 * @JoinColumn(name="production_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * @Id
 */
protected $production;


/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Keyword", inversedBy="keywordProductions")
 * @JoinColumn(name="keyword_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * @Id
 */ 
protected $keyword;
```

Keyword class -

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductionsKeywords", mappedBy="keyword")
 */
protected $keywordProductions;
```

If I write a DQL query like

```
$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery("SELECT p FROM \Entity\Production p");
```

The productions, productionKeywords and keywords all load fine, however if I try to fetch join the productionKeywords and keywords like

```
$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery("SELECT p, pk, k FROM \EntityProduction p 
                         LEFT JOIN p.productionKeywords pk
                         LEFT JOIN pk.keyword k
                         ");
```

then the entities are not loaded.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong as I have the same relationship setup with some other entities and it works fine with them.

Comment: If you do the join and only try to fetch 1 of the entities, does that work? (I mean just select pk instead of p, pk, k for example). Just to be sure, you have the exact same query working on some other entities with the same setup?

Comment: If I select just p it works, if I select p, pk it doesn't. Sorry, I wasn't very clear - I have the same relationship setup with other entities in terms of the annotations between the classes and when I do a query fetching all of the entites it's fine. Would it help if I posted it?

Comment: What do you expect the DQL query to return? Now you are asking for 3 sets of entities. I think you should either get the entire set of p objects, and get their related keywords using your entity classes' methods, or select some specific fields in your DQL query (in which case it will return an array of assoc arrays).

Comment: I'm expecting the query to return hydrated  Productions, ProductionKeywords and Keywords when I use a fetch join, but the ProductionKeywords and Keywords entities are empty.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it seems that if you have a 'pure' join entity (like the ProductionsKeywords class above) then it can't be used in a fetch query. I got around the issue by using a timestamp column in the productions_keywords table as another property in the ProductionsKeywords class and then the fetch joins began to work.